# LiteDB return List of hierarchical data

Tags: c#, litedb

I am new to LiteDb and maybe, I think to much in SQL way, instead of NoSQL way.

I try to receive a list of all child documents, which are defined within a project class.

Therefore, I have two classes generated:

```
 public class Project : INotifyPropertyChanged

{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public List<Title> Titles { get; set; } = new List<Title>();
}
```

And:

```
public class Title : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }


}
```

What I try to achieve is, to get all Titles, which are stored in a specific project document.

I try the following code in C#

```
public async Task<IList<NamespaceTitle>> GetAllNamespacesAsync(string projectTitle)
    {
        var locReturnValue = await Task.Run(
            () =>
            {
                using (var locDataBase = GetLiteDatabase())
                {
                    var locCollection = locDataBase.GetCollection<Project>("projects");
                    var locGetAllTitles = locCollection.
                                            Query().
                                            Include(locTitle => locTitle.Titles).
                                            Where(locProject => locProject.ProjectName == projectTitle).
                                            Select<Title>(locTitles => locTitles.Titles).ToList();
                    return locGetAllTitles;
                }
            });
        return locReturnValue;
    }
```

The compiler error says, that a list can not be converted to Title
But when I change the
"Select(locTitles => locTitles.Titles)" in the query to
"Select<List>(locTitles => locTitles.Titles)",
the compiler error disapears, but then the return type is: "list<list>" !?

Can someone please help me, doing this in a correct way.

THX a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think, I found a solution for my problem.
After querying the data, I found out, that only the Id's of the child elements get saved in the master document.
So, when I do the following. Not sure, if it the common way, but it works.

```
var locProjectCollection = locDataBase.GetCollection<Project>("Project");
            var locGetProjects = locProjectCollection.
                                    Query().
                                    Include(locTitles => locTitles.Titles).
                                    Where(locProject => locProject.ProjectName == projectTitle).
                                    ToList();

            var locGetTitles = locGetProjects.
                               SingleOrDefault()?.
                               Titles.Select(locTitle => locTitle.Id);
            if (locGetTitles.Count() > 0)
            {
                var locTitleCollection = locDataBase.GetCollection<Title>("Title");
                return locTitleCollection.
                       Query().
                       Where(locTitle => locGetTitles.Contains(locTitle.Id)).
                       ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
```

Hope this will help other users as well - or please post an other aproach.